# Python - reading, parsing and writing back to a file

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to read around 5000 lines of code from a text file then parse and store the parsed values into another text file.

However, I am able to only do this for the first 967 lines (as indicated by the output file, which contains the parsed values of the first 967 lines only).

Here is the simple code i wrote to do this job.

```
infile = open("Input.txt", "r")
outfile = open("Output.txt", "w")
for line in infile.readline():
    temp = infile.readline()
    value = temp.split("<_|_>")
    outfile.write(value[1])
```

How would I go about writing the other 4000-odd values?

Comment: You are reading two lines every iteration.  Don't create temp, just use line instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because your `for` iteration is not over the lines in `infile`, but rather over the characters in its first line. Probably, the first line is 967 characters long.

`for line in infile.readline()` means that you're reading the first line from `infile` as a string. Strings are iterable, in the way that iterating over them iterates over the characters in that string. Therefore, you're running the loop each time for every character in that line.

What you want to do is probably, rather, something like this:

```
with open("Input.txt", "r") as infile, open("Output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.split("<_|_>")[0])
```

File objects in Python are also iterable. Iterating over them iterates over each line. You *could* use `for line in infile.readlines()` (Note: `readlines`, not `readline`) instead, but that would read all the lines in `infile` into one huge array before iterating. Iterating directly on the file object only keeps the latest read line in memory at one time.

Comment: i meant to do readlines() only! holy one small mistake becomes one big pain in the ass! Thanks @Dolda2000 for clearing this up with a neat explanation, cheers!

Comment: Now that files are themselves iterators, it is almost never necessary to use readlines(). Use this answer's `for line in infile:` form. Also, +1 for using `with`.

Answer (score 0):

why cant we just use

```
f1 = open('Input.txt','r')
f2 = open('Output.txt','w')

for i in f1:
f2.writelines(i)

f2.close()
```

Comment: Because OP doesn't want to simply copy one file to the other.

Answer (score -1):

You should read each line and parse. you are doing a for loop on a single line in the input file. A simple approach would be to use the while loop

```
f1 = open('Input.txt','r')
f2 = open('Output.txt','w')
line = f1.readline()
while line:    
    value = line.split('<_|_>')
    f2.write(value[0])
    line = f1.readline()
```